Chart.js Line Chart to display values of default and added data
I have a Chart.js Line chart used in React (TS) project , that takes data from user input and displays. However I want to have some default values static to display permanently and as the user inputs data, this should be displayed along with the already existing static data. This is the code I have but not sure how to add initial default values. Also would like to have the X-axis as date.
const BarChart: React.FC = () => {
  const theme = useTheme();
   const [labels, setLabels] = useState<string[]>([]);
  const [values, setValues] = useState<number[]>([]);
  const [dateInput, setDateInput] = useState('');
  const [valueInput, setValueInput] = useState('');

 
  const data = {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'Progress',
        data: values,
        borderColor: 'rgba(75,192,192,1)',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(75,192,192,0.2)',
      },
    ],

  };

  const options = {
    responsive: true,
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        position: 'top' as const,
      },
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Line Chart with User Input',
      },
    },
    scales: {
      x: {
        type: 'time',
        time: {
          unit: 'day',
        },
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: 'Date',
        },
      },
      y: {
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: 'Weight',
        },
      },
    },
  };

  const handleAddDataPoint = () => {
    if (dateInput && valueInput) {
      setLabels((prevLabels) => [...prevLabels, dateInput]);
      setValues((prevValues) => [...prevValues, parseFloat(valueInput)]);
      setDateInput('');
      setValueInput('');
    }
  };


  return (
    <Box sx={{
      padding: theme.spacing(2),
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
      boxShadow: theme.shadows[1],
      borderRadius: theme.shape.borderRadius,
      height: '100%',
      width: '100%',}}
      >
       <Box
        component="form"
        sx={{
          display: 'flex',
          alignItems: 'center',          
          // flexDirection: 'column',
          gap: theme.spacing(1),
          marginBottom: theme.spacing(2),
          '& .MuiTextField-root': { m: 0, width: '25ch' },
        }}
        onSubmit={(e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          handleAddDataPoint();
        }}
      >
        <TextField         
          label="Date"
          type="date"
          value={dateInput}
          onChange={(e) => setDateInput(e.target.value)}
          InputLabelProps={{
            shrink: true,
          }}
          required
        />
        <TextField
          label="Weight"
          type="number"
          value={valueInput}
          onChange={(e) => setValueInput(e.target.value)}
          required
        />
        <Button type="submit" variant="contained" color="primary">
          Add
        </Button>
      </Box>
      <Line data={data} />
    </Box>
  );
};

export default BarChart;


You currently have nothing in data (values to be specific). Set it properly, and then add new values as you get them
